# Installing Flask with Python Pycharm NOT Professional

Tags: pandas, numpy, flask

So I understand that if you have unpaid Pycharm you cannot execute or open Flask?

Is there another IDE for Python where I can install Flask without paying pro?

Bottom line I am trying to learn this program and part of the learning is Flask. If else I pay Pro.

Comment: Pycharm is just an IDE. The Python packages (like Flask) can be installed on your system directly outside of an IDE, then you can just tell Pycharm (or any other IDE) where to find them. Installation of Python packages does not depend on an IDE and don't need you to pay anything. However, the part about "execute" or "open" Flask on "unpaid Pycharm" is not clear.

Comment: Please read flask documentation. [Flask Quickstart](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/)

Comment: Well, Thank you for elucidating on the subject.

Answer (score 0):

Flask can be installed with pip. `pip install flask`

With PyCharm you can make a configuration to run your python file

PyCharm Pro will have better support but community version can definitely do the task.

Also html css and js are better supported in PyCharm Pro

Also for web dev I would suggest VSCode (if you don't wanna pay)